# PHP-like string parsing

Tags: string, swift, parsing

I'm writing a mini-console of sorts and I'm trying to figure out how to extract things from a link. For example, in PHP this is a request variable 
so:

`http://somelink.com/somephp.php?variable1=10&variable2=20`

Then PHP figures out the url parameters and assigns them to a variable.

**How would I parse something like this in Swift?**

So, given the string I'd want to take: variable1=10 and variable2=20 etc, is there a simple way to do this? I tried googling around but didn't really know what I was searching for.

I have a really horrible hacky way of doing this but it's not really extendable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’d be wanting [`NSURLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLComponents/queryItems):

```
import Foundation

let urlStr = "http://somelink.com/somephp.php?variable1=10&variable2=20"
let components = NSURLComponents(string: urlStr)

components?.queryItems?.first?.name   // Optional("variable1")
components?.queryItems?.first?.value  // Optional("10")
```

You might find it helpful to add a `subscript` operator for the query items:

```
extension NSURLComponents {
    subscript(queryItemName: String) -> String? {
        // of course, if you do this a lot, 
        // cache it in a dictionary instead
        for item in self.queryItems ?? [] {
            if item.name == queryItemName {
                return item.value
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

if let components = NSURLComponents(string: urlStr) {
    components["variable1"] ?? "No value"
}
```

Comment: hmm components?.queryItems?.first?.value doesn't seem to return anything?

Comment: also what about variable2? or any other variable other than first?

Comment: `first` is just a quick way to get the first value in an array while being safe in case the array is empty (unlike `queryItems?[0]` which will blow up if there are no query items.  For multiple values, you can do `for…in` over it, have added more code.