# How to get the video ID of a YouTube string

Tags: swift, indexing, character, substring

(XCode 6.3.2, Swift 1.2)
After researching the internet for the whole evening I already know that this can't be done that easily.
I simply want to get the video ID of a YouTube link. So the "ABCDE" in "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"

What I got so far:

```
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"
let characterToFind: Character = "="
let characterIndex = find(url, characterToFind)
println(characterIndex)
url.substringFromIndex(advance(url.startIndex, characterIndex))
```

Prinln outputs: *Optional(31)*
That's right but I can't use this because it's no index.

XCode also states for the last line: *Missing argument for parameter #3 in call*
I also don't know what the 3rd parameter of `substringFromIndex` should be.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `componentsSeparatedByString`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29421928/2631081

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSURL query property as follow:

**Xcode 8.3.1 • Swift 3.1**

```
let link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"
if let videoID = URL(string: link)?.query?.components(separatedBy: "=").last {
    print(videoID) // "ABCDE"
}
```

Another option is to use **URLComponents**:

```
let link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"
if let videoID = URLComponents(string: link)?.queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "v"}).first?.value {
    print(videoID) // "ABCDE"
}
```

---

**Swift 1.x**

```
let link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"
if let videoID = NSURL(string: link)?.query?.componentsSeparatedByString("=").last {
    println(videoID) // "ABCDE"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case there is no need to create an NSURL as other answers do. Just use:

```
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"
if let videoID = url.componentsSeparatedByString("=").last {
    print(videoID)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3+ version:**

```
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"
if let videoID = url.components(separatedBy: "=").last {
    print(videoID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap the optional to use the index:

```
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"
let characterToFind: Character = "="
if let index = find(url, characterToFind) { // Unwrap the optional
  url.substringFromIndex(advance(index, 1)) // => "ABCDE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your url format, you can get the 'v' parameter's value by converting to NSURL then get parameters and separate it by '='.

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAzOOfVA2_8")!
url.query?.componentsSeparatedByString("=").last
```

`url.query` returns `v=RAzOOfVA2_8`

If the link has more than 1 parameter, you can get all parameters then do a loop to verify each parameter:

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAzOOfVA2_8")!
var params = url.query?.componentsSeparatedByString("&")
if let _params = params { //have parameters in URL
    for param in _params { //verify each pair of key & value in your parameters
        var _paramArray = param.componentsSeparatedByString("=") //separate by '=' to get key & value
        if (_paramArray.first?.compare("v", options: nil, range: nil, locale: nil) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame) {
            println(_paramArray.last)
        }
    }
} else {
    //url does not have any parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns an optional – because the character might not be found, in which case it will be `nil`.  You need to unwrap it to check it isn’t and to get the actual value out.

You can also use a range-based `subscript` on the index directly, rather than using `advance` to turn it into an integer index:

```
let url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE"
if let let characterIndex = find(url, "=") {
    let value = url[characterIndex.successor()..<url.endIndex]  // ABCDE
}
else {
    // error handling, if you want it, here
}
```

You have more options if there is a reasonable default in the case of “not found”  For example, if you just want an empty string in that case, this will work:

```
let idx = find(url, "=")?.successor() ?? url.endIndex
let value = url[idx..<url.endIndex]
```

Or, maybe you don’t even need to deal with the optionality right now, so you’re happy to leave the result optional as well:

```
// value will be Optional("ABCD")
let value = find(url, "=").map { url[$0.successor()..<url.endIndex] }
```

For a rundown on optionals, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623568/3925941) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717211/3925941).

Also, rather than hand-parsing URL strings at all, you might find the info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30385803/3925941) useful.